# Sublime text & Linux-KDE. System locales is set to a value that can not handle non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, linux, encoding, sublimetext3, kde-plasma

I'm getting this error when I open ST3. Package control is not working.

> Package Control Your system's local is set to a value that can not
>   handle non ASCII characters. Package Control can not properly work
>   unless this is fixed.
>
> On Linux, please reference your distribution's docs for on properly
>   setting the LANG environmental variable. As a temporary work-around,
>   you can launch Sublime Text from the terminal with:
>
> LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sublime_text

The termporary workaround doesn't work. Also, when I write 'locale' in the terminal I get:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory                                                             
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory                                                          
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory                                                               
LANG=en_EC.UTF-8                                                                                                                     
LANGUAGE=en:es:en                                                                                                                    
LC_CTYPE="en_EC.UTF-8"                                                                                                               
LC_NUMERIC=en_EC.UTF-8                                                                                                               
LC_TIME=en_EC.UTF-8                                                                                                                  
LC_COLLATE="en_EC.UTF-8"                                                                                                             
LC_MONETARY=en_EC.UTF-8                                                                                                              
LC_MESSAGES="en_EC.UTF-8"                                                                                                            
LC_PAPER=en_EC.UTF-8                                                                                                                 
LC_NAME=en_EC.UTF-8                                                                                                                  
LC_ADDRESS=en_EC.UTF-8                                                                                                               
LC_TELEPHONE=en_EC.UTF-8                                                                                                             
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_EC.UTF-8                                                                                                           
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_EC.UTF-8                                                                                                        
LC_ALL=
```

Please help. I'm on Ubuntu+KDE, Im coding blindly now with no sublime packages installed.

Comment: Does it help when you set `export LANG=en_us.UTF-8`?

Comment: No it didn't help. Anyway, shifted to Unity and problem solved. So, it is an issue of KDE. I'll inlclude it in the question and in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while attempting to install Package Control on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS via [the prescribed method](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) within Chroot of ChromeOS, Sublime Text Build 3083.

A sensible solution for this problem exists in a duplicate of this issue here: https://askubuntu.com/a/440341/200027

The solution involves adding "bash -c "LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text" to the appropriate Exec lines of Sublime's .desktop unity launch file located at /usr/applications/share/sublime_text.desktop as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=bash -c "LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F"
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=bash -c "LANG=en_US.UTF-8/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n"
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec= bash -c "LANG=en_US.UTF-8/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file"
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Note that you will need sudo to edit that desktop launch file.

Comment: Editing sublime_text.desktop Exec under the desktop entry seems to have fixed it for me on xfce4. But the file was here: /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop