# Sublime package LANG setting

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have downloaded and unzipped Sublime 3 package for Red Hat linux. I have sublime_text in my /downloads/sublime_text_3.

When I open ./sublime_text, I get the following error

```
Package Control

Your system's locale is set to a value that can not handle non-ASCII characters. Package Control can not properly work unless this is fixed.

On Linux, please reference your distribution's docs for information on properly setting the LANG environmental variable. As a temporary work-around, you can launch Sublime Text from the terminal with:

LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sublime_text
```

I tried changing `setenv LANG en_US.UTF-8` with no positive effects.

Comment: try `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 sublime_text` as per https://github.com/wbond/package_control/commit/6243fc699b1756916772b85434ae440519748107

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried changing the sublime_text.desktop to the above command. But the package control error remains.

Comment: Does it work if you run it from the console that way? Above you just mentioned using setenv to do it, but perhaps that wasn't propagated to the app? (that's not a construct I generally use).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried the solutions given in the [package control issue on Github](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/532)?

If `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sublime_text` and `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 sublime_text` don't work, you can try the following:

> Define a system wide locale [...]:
>
> in `/etc/locale.conf`:
>
> ```
> LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
> ```
>
> And reboot your sytem.

or

> simply changing only the LANG variable in `/etc/locale.conf` from my
>   default setting to `en_US.UTF-8`, as so --
>
> /etc/locale.conf:
>
> ```
> LANG=en_US.UTF-8
> LC_CTYPE="C"
> LC_NUMERIC="C"
> LC_TIME="C"
> LC_COLLATE="C"
> LC_MONETARY="C"
> LC_MESSAGES="C"
> LC_PAPER="C"
> LC_NAME="C"
> LC_ADDRESS="C"
> LC_TELEPHONE="C"
> LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
> LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
> LC_ALL=
> ```
>
> -- but Package Control continued to throw the error until I culled the file down to only the first line --
>
> /etc/locale.conf:
>
> ```
> LANG=en_US.UTF-8
> ```
>
> Hope that helps someone!

You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107032/sublime-text-linux-kde-system-locales-is-set-to-a-value-that-can-not-handle-n).

Comment: Thanks Andreas. It worked after setting LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8. I am not sure why it did not work only with LANG setting

Answer (score 1):

For those **without sudo** (e.g. on enterprise CentOS), clear `LC_ALL`, set `LANG`, then run:

```
setenv LC_ALL ''
setenv LANG en_US.UTF-8
subl
```

Here's a one-liner launcher for `csh`:

```
/usr/bin/csh -c "setenv LC_ALL '' && setenv LANG en_US.UTF-8 && subl"
```

Comment: Setting LC_ALL to empty string solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

## vim /etc/locale.gen

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8  
en_US ISO-8859-1
```

## locale-gen

vim /etc/locale.conf

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

## locale

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set system locale using

**/etc/locale.conf**

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

OR
Simply run this command

```
localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have an export of `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, or `LC_CTYPE` in your ~/.bashrc file, your ~/.profile file, or some other file that modifies your path. When I commented out `export LC_ALL="C"` from my ~/.bashrc (I can't remember why I put it there originally), the message stopped appearing on `subl` startup for me.

This was true even after I deleted the two lines I added to /etc/locale.conf per the top answer (restoring it to its original condition of no contents or nonexistent), and rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for kali linux**

Hey I know this is kind of solved but I spent time finding a solution for Kali Linux. According with this guy (https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/where-does-st3-look-for-locale-settings/48206) this bug happens when connecting through remote desktop not sure if this is right but it was my case.

The solution is the one above:
Running LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 sublime_text.

If you are like me and like to run everything fast in the terminal then:

**a)** cd to /usr/bin

**b)** sudo nano subl (*if you don't have it try: sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin/subl*)

**c)** Make sure your file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
```